# Trying to have a fixed image changing by the section

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to keep an image at fixed position, but changing the image at each section. Preferably without JavaScript, or with as little as possible (or, if it makes sense for a total JavaScript-Noob like myself...).

Anyone got any ideas? Feels like I've been watch myself blind on the code:

```
<div class="left">
     <img src="../img/orange.png" alt="orange" id="orange" />
     <img src="../img/banana.png" alt="banana" id="banana" />
     <img src="../img/apple.png" alt="apple" id="apple" />
</div>

<div class="right">
    <section id="section_orange">
       <h2>about</h2>
       <p>Something about oranges.</p>
     </section>

    <section id="section_banana">
        <h2>about bananas</h2>
        <p>Something about bananas.</p>
    </section>

    <section id="section_apple">
        <h2>about apples</h2>
        <p>Something about apples.</p>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: This will require javascript. I suggest you look into Jquery and scrolling events. Scrollspy is a good plugin.

Comment: your question is confusing the content will scroll and you want to change the image?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get the image to line up with the section, you could split it into rows, instead of having the images in one div and the text in another. Then use css to put the image on the left, and text on the right.

```
<section>
<article id="section_orange">
   <img src="../img/orange.png" alt="orange" id="orange" />  
   <h2>about</h2>
   <p>Something about oranges.</p>
 </article>

<article id="section_banana">
    <img src="../img/banana.png" alt="banana" id="banana" />
    <h2>about bananas</h2>
    <p>Something about bananas.</p>
</article>

<article id="section_apple">
    <img src="../img/apple.png" alt="apple" id="apple" />
    <h2>about apples</h2>
    <p>Something about apples.</p>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont really get what you want.

like this?

http://www.ringana.com/de/ueber-uns/so-fresh/

that could be achieved easily by changing the img to an background-img and give the div with the bg the css value : background-attachment:fixed;

see background-attachment here : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-attachment.asp

Comment: If you need clarification, post a comment.

Comment: You don't answer if you don't understand the question.  Instead, this should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are a newbie at JavaScript, but JS would need to be used to change the image to each section.  To help you understand I commented on the below code.

```js
function placeimgs() {

  var fruit = ["orange", "banana", "apple"]; 
  // Creates an array that contains your fruit names to be used later.

  for (i = 0; i < fruit.length; i++) {
  // We use a "for" loop to run the folling code multiple times.  It means this:
  // "i" is set to 0, run the code while "i" is less than the number of items in "fruit".
  // Each time we run the code, add the number 1 to "i".
  // Note: In JS, the first item in an array is "0" the second is "1" and so on . . .

    document.getElementById('section_' + fruit[i]).innerHTML = document.getElementById('section_' + fruit[i]).innerHTML + '<img src="../img/' + fruit[i] + '.png" alt="' + fruit[i] + ' " id="' + fruit[i] + '"/>';
    
    // Each time we run this code, put the number "i" into the places that I did.
    // That will change which pictures are being displayed.

  }

  document.getElementById('button1').style.display = "none";
  
  // Hide the button after it is clicked.  Notice that this code is outside of the "for" loop.
  // That way we "hide" the button only once.

}
```

```html
<div class="right">
  <section id="section_orange">
    <h2>about</h2>
    <p>Something about oranges.</p>
  </section>

  <section id="section_banana">
    <h2>about bananas</h2>
    <p>Something about bananas.</p>
  </section>

  <section id="section_apple">
    <h2>about apples</h2>
    <p>Something about apples.</p>
  </section>
</div>

<button onclick="placeimgs()" id="button1">Place Images</button><br>
When you click this button, it will call function "placeimgs".
```

Hope this helps!